# Google Calendar API does not send notifications

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with Google Calendar API. I'm creating a new channel to receive notifications. Here's request created by Guzzle and Google Client and successful subscribing response:

```
POST /calendar/v3/calendars/info@mycalendaremail.com/events/watch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Guzzle/5.3.1 curl/7.49.1 PHP/7.1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":"nctest-827009","type":"web_hook","address":"https:\/\/f7487d73.ngrok.io\/api\/catch-google-calendar-notification","expiration":"1510133420000"}  

POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Guzzle/5.3.1 curl/7.49.1 PHP/7.1.1

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJuYWtlZGNhcnBldUNAbmMtY2FsZW2kYXItMTg0MzA2LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbVwvb2F1dGgyXC92NFwvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE1MDk1Mjg2MjAsImlhdCI6MTUwOTUyNDk2MCwic7NvcGUiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tFC9hdXRoXC9jYWxlbmRhciJ9.T5Jqz1sSsBHKqSDTQIVK79CJQOVaXvlD89UwURguz83wq-Z6fMEKnys-1ICOmRfv0l3mrOb-Xu44RuoA5JcBAipQh0U_Pd99hQFI-723ff98JWggSwhSz1iz-tpKDEqih8YSE8LltGUwfj94_tkip-bLUyqJwOgCbGkh3KfMQdRGAwjxSipmy72VzePCO2qfMs7z77H7PTD_CynkISbuRB_EYyjgXfGoFE8-nFFjBZ7lRdueHejyMXxNCaV0uSf9N_7BcrAa6uyY-7_a60qo4yoVeZNg5I_62zgQc0BZiJQywIEcrTm9LGPm14WaPkKQa4Kpxa4ymbLwmVnEjwCaxQ  

{
 "kind": "api#channel",
 "id": "nctest-827009",
 "resourceId": "rRZHlhKrOO9wkcNdNFIBOZsUjHg",
 "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/info@mycalendaremail.com/events?maxResults=250&alt=json",
 "expiration": "1510133420000"
}
```

When I'm trying to do exactly the same with newly created calendar, it works perfectly. I mean I'm subscribing and getting notifications.

With the existing calendar, I'm subscribing and not getting notifications.

The domain is the same. The code is the same. The server is the same.

The are no any error messages. I wonder how can I make it work with the existing calendar?

Comment: Google calendar is not really consistent with notifications. I also had the same issue. Actually, notifications eventually come but it might be after several minutes -sometimes +15 minutes in my case-. I also added an additional code that checks periodically if there are any changes in calendars. I don't think there is an existing solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Do check if its linked to an app update where-in gmail did not have access to calendar.