# google calendar incremental sync on cron

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created a google calendar incremental sync and running it through cron to make it perfect i have make cron to run every minute and today got an email from google that

> Limiting access to data in your Google Account
>
> Hello,
>
> Although you don’t need to take any action, we wanted to let you know
>   that the following third-party apps will no longer be able to access
>   some data in your Google Account, including your Gmail content. This
>   change will go into effect starting March 31, 2019.
>
> MY-APPLICATION-NAME

how can i manage to make my app perfect with incremental sync every minute cron is not a solution.

I have setup push notifications but which is not 100% reliable some time i receive notification some time no notification  google saying in documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) and some posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051018/google-calendar-api-does-not-send-notifications#comment81213054_47051018).

> Notifications are not 100% reliable. Expect a small percentage of
>   messages to get dropped under normal working conditions. Make sure to
>   handle these missing messages gracefully, so that the application
>   still syncs even if no push messages are received.

Comment: This appears to be two questions.  What exactly is your issue?  The email from google?  Or that not all the notifications are coming though?

Comment: Did you submit your app for review? This policy change was outlined in Google's article [Elevating user trust in our API ecosystem](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/elevating-user-trust-in-our-api-ecosystems). I could not find any details on whether access to these features could be submitted for review after the upcoming change. I saw IFTTT is disabling some G-Suite functions due to this coming update. Maybe (and I'm being optimistic) they will let you re-authorize with OAuth with the new permissions